# Probability of winning a specific game..

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider the following game. The player rolls a fair die. If he rolls 3 or less, he loses
immediately. Otherwise he selects, at random, as many cards from a full deck as the
number that came up on the die. The player wins if all four Aces are among the selected
cards.
The solution is :
Let W be the event that the player wins. Let Fi be the event that he rolls i, where
i = 1; : : : ; 6; P(Fi) = 1
6 .
Since we lose if we roll a 1, 2, or 3, $P(W|F1) = P(W|F2) = P(W|F3) = 0$.
Moreover,
$P(W|F4)=1/(52C4), P(W|F5)=(5C4)/(52C5),P(W|F6)=(6C5)/(52C4)$.
Therefore,  $P(W)= 1/6*1/(52C4)(1+(5C4)+(6C4))$.
I am not able to understand $P(W|F4),P(W|F5),P(W|F6)$.
The above solution is a textbook solution.

Comment: Please use MathJax for typesetting mathematical terms. [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: P(W|Fi) means "probability to win provided that die showed up $i $".

Answer (score 1):

The probability of winning given that he rolls $5$ is the probability that the first five cards selected from the deck include all four aces. This is equal to the probability that cards $1,2,3,4$, plus the probability that cards $1,2,3,5$ are all aces, plus the probability that cards $1,2,4,5$ are, plus the probability for $1,3,4,5$ and $2,3,4,5$.

Note that all these events are disjoint, so that you can just sum the probabilities, and all are the same if the pack is randomised. Each one is the probability that four specific cards are the four aces; since there are ${}^{52}C_4$ possibilities for the four cards, only one of which is all four aces, this probability is $1/{}^{52}C_4$. But we needed to add ${}^5C_4$ copies of this, for the different positions in the five cards the four aces could be, giving ${}^5C_4/{}^{52}C_4$. The other cases are similar.

Comment: Actually there was a mistype P(Fi)=1/6.

Comment: Also P(W|F5)=(5C4)/(52C4). I am not able to understand the denomenator . Why 52c4, whys it is not 52C5 inspite of selecting 5 cards.

Comment: @MathsGeek You could work it out as ${}^{48}C_1/{}^{52}C_5$, by counting all possible combinations of 5 cards including all aces, and dividing by the total number of five-card combinations. I think that is actually the more natural way to do it. The two expressions ${}^{48}C_1/{}^{52}C_5$ and ${}^5C_4/{}^{52}C_4$ are equal - both methods are equally valid.

Comment: Can u explain about 48C1. As far as i can infer you have excluded 4 of Aces right ?

Comment: Can u explain once again about 48C1?